# How to set custom DNS for all users using Ubuntu as Wifi Hotspot?

Tags: wireless, dns, router

I use my laptop as wifi hotspot with an "ad-hoc network" instead of a normal wifi router.

The question is: how can i set custom dns for all the hotspot's user so i can create new domains that will work only in my private network?

EDIT: I also need to block some other sites through DNS